# How to installl eth-lightWallet?

Tags: light-clients

I am trying to install the ethereum-lightwallet on my system.  I am experiencing a problem with npm.  When I run `npm install eth-lightwallet` I get a message:

```
 └─┬ eth-lightwallet@2.5.2 
  ├── bignumber.js@2.0.7  (git://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git#94d7146671b9719e00a09c29b01a691bc85048c2)
  └─┬ web3@0.15.3
    └── bignumber.js@2.0.7  (git+https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git#94d7146671b9719e00a09c29b01a691bc85048c2)

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/m/package.json'
npm WARN m No description
npm WARN m No repository field.
npm WARN m No README data
npm WARN m No license field.
```

Then if I try creating a `package.json` file in the directory I want to install the lightwallet I get a message that:

```
    npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-69-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/home/m/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.0/bin/node"      "/home/m/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.0/bin/npm" "install" "eth-lightwallet"
    npm ERR! node v6.3.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
    npm ERR! code ENOSELF

    npm ERR! Refusing to install eth-lightwallet as a dependency of itself
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to install the lightwallet?  I've also tried `npm init` but I'm not sure what variables to add to create the package.json file.

Comment: Have you tried doing npm install eth-ligtwallet -g? Are you sure your path isn't screwed up? Having screwy paths with npm (and especially homebrew) can seriously cause massive headaches. Other than that, i recommend finding a package.json file that you know works and then changing it to just be eth-ligtwallet